# why the control button do not work in my slideshow?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I make slideshow width 4 photos that appear with opacity: 1 and z-index: 2, and I could make it run automatically, but to control it, not yet and this is my js code with some of jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 0
function next() {
    move(i++);
    if (i === 4) {
        i = 0
    }
    console.log("first i = " + i)
};
setInterval(next, 2000);
function move(n) {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img')
    var img = images[n]
    $(img).addClass('showSlide')
    $(img).removeClass('hideSlide')
    $(img).siblings(".img").addClass('hideSlide')
}
$('.next').click(

    () => {
        if (i === 3) {
            i = 0
        };
        move(i++);
        console.log("next i = " + i)
    }
)
$('.previous').click(
    () => {
        if (i === 0) {
            i = 3
        };
        move(i--);
        console.log("previous i = " + i)
    }
)})
```

my automatic slide work but when I click the next or the previous button the slide do not continue from the last position ,and my HTML code is :

```
 <div class="container">
        <button class="next">next</button>
        <button class="previous">previous</button>
        <img class="img" src="gallery-img7.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="img" src="gallery-img2.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="img" src="gallery-img8.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="img" src="gallery-img3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked console for errors?

Comment: yeah , and I did not find any errors!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you are handling increment and decriment might be the issue? This is a good use case for modulo %. I also cleared and reset the interval after button click to get the same interval on the newly shown image. Here's an example that seems to work as your intending:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 0
function next() {
    move(i++);
};

let nextInterval = setInterval(next, 2000);
function move(n) {
    clearInterval(nextInterval)
    nextInterval = setInterval(next, 2000);
    n = i%4;
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img')
    var img = images[n]
    $(img).addClass('showSlide')
    $(img).removeClass('hideSlide')
    $(img).siblings(".img").addClass('hideSlide')
}
$('.next').click(

    () => {
        move(i++);
    }
)
$('.previous').click(
    () => {
        move(i--);
    }
)})
```

```css
.img{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
.showSlide{
  display:block;
}
.hideSlide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
        <button class="next">next</button>
        <button class="previous">previous</button>
        <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=1" alt="">
        <img class="img hideSlide"   src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=2" alt="">
        <img class="img hideSlide"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=3" alt="">
        <img class="img hideSlide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=4" alt="">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code to trigger the next and previous clicks is basically working, the Interval function you are running is never interrupted by your button clicks, so the slideshow continues to cycle around.

Your classes to show and hide may not be attaching to the DOM properly either. I find it's a good practice to attach less specific classes before I attach a specific one, i.e. blanket hide all slides and then show the selected slide.

Another technique that I think is helpful is to try and figure out the manual user interaction first and then base my automation on it. I've worked up an alteration of the code you posted, where the slides 'slide' themselves by triggering the next action, similarly to how a user would.

So the slideshow should start itself on page load by use of a setInterval being declared. That setInterval is interrupted when the user moves the mouse into the slideshow area - this way the button will control the active/shown slide. If you move the mouse off or away from the slideshow container the setInterval is allowed to kick in again, and the slides should cycle around automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;

        function move(n) {
            var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
            var img = images[n];
            $(img).siblings(".img").addClass('hideSlide');
            $(img).siblings(".img").removeClass('showSlide');
            $(img).addClass('showSlide');
            $(img).removeClass('hideSlide');
        }

        var next = setInterval(autoRotate, 2000);

        function autoRotate() {
            $('.next').trigger('click');
        }

        $('.container').on('mouseenter', function() {
          clearInterval(next);
        });

        $('.container').on('mouseleave', function() {
          next = setInterval(autoRotate, 2000);
        });


        $('.next').click(() => {
           if (i === 3) {
             i = 0;
           } else {
            i++;
           }
           move(i);
        });

        $('.previous').click(() => {
            if (i === 0) {
              i = 3;
            } else {
                i--;
            }
            move(i);
        });
    })
```

Comment: thank you so much , this is a new idea for me, your are a genius!!